# Why does this regex only half work?

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to use a regex to match another line in a VMX file but it only "half" works. I will explain.

The line I am trying to match for example is `scsi0:0.fileName = "Test01.vmdk`. My regex seems to work fine for that. Now the curveball, if I try to use the same regex to look for `scsi0:1.fileName = "Test01_1.vmdk`. My regex does not find it and only display the first disk it found for each VM. I know I am missing something I just can't put my finger on it. The only thing that is odd but I don't think makes any difference is the line for the second disk `scsi0:1.fileName = "Test01_1.vmdk` is located at the bottom of the file and the line for `scsi0:0.fileName = "Test01.vmdk` is at the middle of the file with more lines for other option after it. Is the regex stopping too soon? Is that even possible?

Anyhow here is the code block I am working on.

```
    foreach my $vm (@virtual_machines) {
    my $vmx_file = $ssh1->capture("cat $virtual_machines{$vm}{VMX}");
    my $inc = -1;
    if ($vmx_file =~ m/scsi([0-3]):([0-9]|1[0-5])\.fileName\s+=\s+"(?<DISK>\w+?\.vmdk)"/xm) {
        ++$inc;
        $virtual_disks{$vm}{"Disk$inc"} = "$+{DISK}";
    }
```

This is odd, but if I explicitly plug in the numbers of the SCSI id I am looking for it work. For some reason it is not able to find it on its own. I updated my example too.

Comment: But in my case doesn't the .+ take into account everything from A-Z,a-z,0-9 and underscore and hyphen?

Comment: Not the answer to the question at hand, but I think you'll find that your '[0-15]' character class won't do what you want. That will match 0, 1, or 5.

Comment: I changed it but there seems to be something else causing it to not work, still that needed to be changed anyway.

Comment: Please don't change the original code, but rather post the new code as a clearly marked update. Otherwise it makes the answers look wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to find all matches in a string, change the `if` to a `while` and add the `g` modifier for global matching. @mob is also right that you should use non-greedy matching.

The character group `[0-15]` is equivalent to `[015]`: if you want to match 0-15, then you should change this to `(?:[0-9]|1[0-5])`. You don't need to escape the `:`. And I assume you left out the closing `"` in your strings by mistake when typing the question.

Works on [rubular](http://rubular.com/r/HsLxVsYWQa).

Comment: I tried using a "while" and it causes my script run in a continuous loop until I ^C out of it.

Comment: @Solignis Oh, you'll also need to add the `g` modifier at the end of the regex. See [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/perl.html).

Comment: It works! Making it a while loop rather than an if statment did it

Comment: Just to test it I added another disk to the VM and it added to the hash just like it should. Thanks!

Comment: I did not think to use a while loop because I thought you would have to have a condition to break the loop but that is what the regex does when it runs out of text.

Comment: @Solignis It maintains state between iterations and works like a generator.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose this may be the culprit

```
[0-15]
```

this means the following digits: 0, 1, 5. Whereas you probably meant

```
([0-9]|1[0-5])
```

i.e. all numbers in the range [0 15]

Comment: this doesn't really explain why it's not matching the digit 1 in "scsi0:1", though...

Answer (score 1):

I'd be concerned that `"(?<DISK>.+)"` section of the regex is too greedy and captures everything up to the *last* quotation mark in the (multi-line?) input rather than the *next* quotation mark.

I'd try something like

```
"(?<DISK>[^"]+)"
```

which is to say, match one or more chars that are not quotation marks.

Comment: using .+? will make it ungreedy.

Comment: I tried that but I had errors in my code so I will see what making ungreedy will do.

Answer (score 0):

Some things you could try:
`/scsi[0-3] : (?:[0-9]|1[0-5]) \. fileName \s*=\s* "(?<DISK>.+?)"/xs`